# Live-update, dynamic content windows in Java

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jlist, joptionpane

I have been trying to make a program that creates a dialog, checks the first n numbers (specified by int y in the code below) if they are prime numbers, and then prints the output into the window like this:

> 1 - True
>   2 - True
>   3 - True
>   4 - False
>   5 - True

etc...

I had trouble figuring out how to make it dynamic and live (i.e refreshing) but someone on another forum suggested using a Jlist and setting that as the content, and I did (as you can see below), but...

1. The window is not nearly 700x700 and the list isn't either.
2. The list is empty, or at least I think so, because all I get is a window with the default size, and a white line as the only content.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class main {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //make new string jlist, add numstr to it, and set list as contents 
    of window.

    String NumberStr = "";

    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    listModel.addElement(NumberStr); 

    JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);

    JOptionPane Window = new JOptionPane();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Window, list, "Prime Number Generator", 
    JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
    Window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));
    list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    Window.setVisible(true);
    //check if prime, append, update
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    while (y<100){
        if (isPrime(z) == true){
            NumberStr += z + " true";
        } else {
            NumberStr += z + " false";
        }
        y++;
        z++;
    }
}

public static boolean isPrime (int x){
    int i = 1;
    boolean result = false;
    while (i<=x){
        if (i%x<0) {
            result = true;
        }else{
            result = false;;
        }
        i++;
        }
    return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: To have a Swing GUI update as a your prime calculations are ongoing, you will need to run the calculations in a background thread. Instead, it would be much easier to do all your calculations, save the String results to the JList's model (something that you're not doing -- you're simply ignoring the String returned), and then when all calculations are done, display your JList. If you go the simpler latter route, you still need to do something with your NumberStr variable once you've created it -- you need to add it to your JList's model. So, create a `DefaultListModel<String>` object, ...

Comment: ... use it to create your JList (pass your model object above into the JList's constructor), and every time you create a new numberStr variable, add it to the model using its `addElement(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating Strings here:

```
while (y<100){
    if (isPrime(z) == true){  
        NumberStr += z + " true";
    } else {
        NumberStr += z + " false";
    }
    y++;
    z++;
}
```

but you're doing nothing with them, so nothing will display.

you want to use a JList, then:

- When creating your new number Strings, add them to the model: `model.addElement(numberStr);`
- Best to display the GUI after all calculations are done.
- Add the JList to a JScrollPane before displaying
- Don't create two JOptionPanes as you're doing (and you're displaying the wrong one).
- Don't restrict the size of the JList. Instead restrict the row count.
- If you absolutely want to first display the GUI and then update it with long-running code, you're going to have to use a separate thread to do the calculation and will need to queue the result onto the model with care and on the Swing event thread. Are you sure that you want to do this?

Note also,

- `if (isPrime(z) == true){` should be the simpler `if (isPrime(z)) {`
- All variables should start with a lower-case letter, so numberStr, not NumberStr.

Key is the while loop -- you need to store the Strings created there:

```
while (y<100){
    if (isPrime(z)){  
        model.addElement(z + " true");
    } else {
        model.addElement(z + " false");
    }
    y++;
    z++;
}
```

Even better:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

        // get rid of this, doesn't help
        // listModel.addElement(numberStr);

        JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);

        // don't restrict the list's size, rather set its row count
        // list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        list.setVisibleRowCount(10);

        // check if prime, append, update
        int y = 0;
        while (y < 100) {
            listModel.addElement(String.format("%d %b", y, isPrime(y)));
            y++;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
    }

    // simplify
    public static boolean isPrime(int x) {
        int i = 2;
        while (i < x) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                return false;
            } 
            i++;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what you mean by "Im doing nothing with them"... I HAVE created a model and added Numstr into it here:

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
listModel.addElement(NumberStr); 
JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);
```

Haven't I?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I now see the model, but what I'm talking about is within your while loop -- you do nothing with the String objects created within the while loop.

Comment: See further edits to answer. Your mistake I think is that you're adding a blank String to the list model, and then in the while loop, you're changing the String that the String variable refers to -- but this has no effect on the original String that was added to the list model -- it's still blank. This gets to the core difference between variables and objects. String objects are immutable and can't be changed, and so every time you call += on your String variable, you're creating a new String, but the original String object is again unchanged.